# SQLServer Update Trigger with empty DELETED logical table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I create a update trigger on a table to audit data changes...

the code used is:

```
   ALTER TRIGGER dbo.Tg_table_upd ON dbo.table
FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @DATA DATETIME= GETDATE();
DECLARE @USER VARCHAR(20);
SELECT       
      @USER = CONVERT(VARCHAR, context_info)
      FROM  master..sysprocesses
      WHERE spid = @@SPID;

       INSERT INTO table_LOG
       SELECT      
            *, 
            @USER, 
            @DATA, 
            0
            FROM deleted;

END;
```

Do some tests and **its working**...when I run a update in dbo.table **I got 1 or more rows inserted in may audit table table_log**.
But in a strange situation...when a java application run a specific update code (captured by SQL Profiler):

```
DECLARE @P1 INT;

SET @P1 = 68235;

EXEC sp_prepexec 
    @P1 OUTPUT, 
    N'@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 bigint,@P2 bigint,@P3 bigint,@P4 bigint,@P5 bigint,@P6 bigint,@P7 bigint,@P8 bigint,@P9 bigint,@P10 bigint,@P11 bigint,@P12 bigint,@P13 bigint,@P14 bigint,@P15 bigint,@P16 bigint,@P17 bigint,@P18 bigint,@P19 bigint,@P20 bigint,@P21 bigint,@P22 bigint,@P23 bigint,@P24 bigint,@P25 bigint,@P26 bigint,@P27 bigint,@P28 bigint,@P29 bigint,@P30 nvarchar(4000)', 
    N'update table set irc_status=@P0 where (irc_id in (@P1 , @P2 , @P3 , @P4 , @P5 , @P6 , @P7 , @P8 , @P9 , @P10 , @P11 , @P12 , @P13 , @P14 , @P15 , @P16 , @P17 , @P18 , @P19 , @P20 , @P21 , @P22 , @P23 , @P24 , @P25 , @P26 , @P27 , @P28 , @P29)) and irc_status=@P30                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ', 
    N'XXX', 
    58074, 
    58079, 
    58082, 
    58086, 
    58091, 
    58095, 
    57880, 
    57879, 
    57874, 
    57873, 
    57953, 
    57959, 
    57954, 
    57960, 
    57785, 
    57790, 
    57779, 
    57784, 
    59113, 
    59110, 
    59116, 
    59119, 
    75840, 
    75851, 
    75843, 
    75852, 
    75834, 
    75844, 
    75842, 
    N'YYY';

SELECT 
      @P1;
```

The source table is updated (6 rows affected)...
But I get no rows in my audit table (table_log)
Looking foward in sql profiler... I can confirm the trigger was accioned but when run the statement

```
  SELECT      
            *, 
            @USER, 
            @DATA, 
            0
            FROM deleted;
```

SQL profiler shows 0 rows affected... So.. the update was commited...(6 ros affected... the trigger was fired... but have a empty "Deleted" Logical table...
Why??

Comment: Why are you using `sysprocesses` to get the user? What's wrong with `CURRENT_USER` or `SYSTEM_USER`?

Comment: I would put the trigger code in a TRY .. CATCH block and do some error handling to get some more visibility into what's happening.   Maybe `varchar(20)` isn't big enough to hold all values of `user`?

Comment: @Larnu I use context to get real user (from AD) since the app use a single database user to connect...it's setting by another code... long history... but this part of code works...since how i said.. any other update statement issued works fine... even by the java app...this statement specific (in my post) have a strange behavior

Comment: @TabAlleman , that's not the case, just incase  I already remove this  extra part of code...but without success... and SQL Profiler don't  catch any exception  in both cases too... the code runs with no errors