# SQL server triggers : Deleted table empty after update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a database A, table t with a transactional replication to a database B table t

on B.t there is a trigger

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[synchro_trigger]
ON [dbo].[t]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- update case
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM Deleted )
...
```

when running an update on A.t :

```
update A.t set field1='1' where id=?
```

the value is replicated then the trigger is called and `SELECT 0 FROM Deleted` exist;
the trigger does its job.

When updating ALL fields on table t (some get a different value, some get the same value)

```
update A.t set field1='1', field2='1', ... where id=?
```

the values (which are differents) are replicated then the triggrer is called BUT `SELECT 0 FROM Deleted` doesn't exist.

so the trigger does nothing, it is not what I want.

In case of update the previous row value is supposed to be inside Deleted, right?
How it is possible that the trigger doesn't receive the previous value inside the Delete table ?

Note :
it looks like the same issue as : [SQLServer Update Trigger with empty DELETED logical table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689540/sqlserver-update-trigger-with-empty-deleted-logical-table)

Comment: *"`SELECT 0 FROM Deleted` doesn't exist."* the `deleted` object *always* exists in an `TRIGGER`, even just on an `insert`; there's something you aren't telling us here.

Comment: 1) Is the body of your trigger written to handle multiple-row INSERTs and UPDATEs, or does your code only work with single-row INSERTs and UPDATEs?
2) What version of SQL Server are you using?
3) Does your trigger really need that IF statement?  Or could you instead write it to be more focused on the DESTINATION table, e.g.
INSERT B.t (columns)
             SELECT columns FROM inserted LEFT JOIN B.T
                         ON B.T.id = inserted.id
             WHERE B.T.id IS NULL -- e.g. doesn't exist
(with an appropriate UPDATE statement preceding INSERT...)

Comment: Does anything in Ben Herron's answer here apply to you? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ade38112-9a87-4474-bf5c-6389e7ae3e26/trigger-in-the-subscription-database-transactional-replication?forum=sqlreplication

Comment: 1) it can handle multiple row 
2) sql server 2019
3) I need the If to compare if a specific field changed its values (0->1), (I join delete and Insert on the id column where deleted.f=0 and inserted.f=1 )

Comment: @Larnu I also believed but  IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM Deleted ) is false, I tried adding a NOT and the code was executed

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Aside... you really should be using the correct `dbo.t` in your table object references. `A.dbo.t` is frowned upon because it's 3-part naming and `A.t` could break existing code if you ever add a new `A` schema to your `A` database.

Comment: The `deleted` virtual table will always exist but `IF EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM Deleted )` is only true if there is at least one row updated. i.e.: Is the `id` used in the update statement matching an existing row?